# Find sum where user has to enter a command with parameters such as 'sum(par1, par2,...)'

Tags: c

User enters command with parameters.There are no errors, but I am having trouble with the weird output.
I took input as string, identified if the input matches the command 'sum', if it does then extracted the parameters in between sum[], stored them in an array and send them as arguments to sum function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int sumOfArray(int arr[])
{
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i++;i<sizeof(arr))
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
printf("%d\n",sum);
return sum;
}

int main()
{
char input[256];
int j=0,temp=0;
int arraySum[6]={0};
printf("user_account $> ");
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);            
if (input[0]=='s' && input[1]=='u' && input[2]=='m')
{
    if (input[3]!='(')
    {
        printf("Please enter proper parameters : sum(num1, num2, ..)\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 4; i++; input[i] < ']')
        {
            if (input[i] !=',')
            {
                if (!isdigit(input[i]))
                {
                    printf("Please enter only digits\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = int(input[i]);
                    printf("%d\n",temp);
                    arraySum[j] = arraySum[j]*10 + temp;

                }
            }
            else j++;
        }

    }
    sumOfArray(arraySum);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you accounting for the space after the , ?

Comment: This loop: `for (int i = 4; i++; input[i] < ']')` has the update and termination condition parts swapped. The condition `input[i] < ']'` also looks quite suspicious; it compares ASCII values, not wheter the pointer is left of a closing bracket. (And you require round opening parantheses, but square closing brackets?)

Comment: Also how does the termination condition (`input[i] < ']'`) make sense? Reading well beyond the boundary of the `input` array is almost guaranteed. You would probably want to use `strlen(input).`

Comment: `for(int i=0;i++;i<sizeof(arr))` --> `for(int i=0;i<size_of_arr;i++)` ,( sizeof(arr) is size  of pointer to int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int sumOfPara(void){
    int v, sum = 0;
    char ch;

    while(1){
        if(2 == fscanf(stdin, "%d %c", &v, &ch) && (ch == ',' || ch == ')')){
            sum += v;
            if(ch == ')')
                break;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Parameter is invalid.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void){
    char command[32];
    char left_paren;

    printf("user_account $> ");
    if(2 != fscanf(stdin, "%31[a-z] %c", command, &left_paren) || strcmp(command, "sum") != 0 || left_paren != '('){
        fprintf(stderr, "Please enter proper parameters : sum(num1, num2, ..)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else { //rest
        printf("%d\n", sumOfPara());
    }
    return 0;
}
```